# When creating a new data object in Ember that relies on another object how do you pass it along?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I am on a page where I can see a specific customer, part of my router.js is:

```
this.route('customers');
this.route('customer', {path: "customers/:customer_id"});
this.route('customer.order.create', { path: "customers/:customer_id/order/create" });
```

customer.order.create needs to load in my main view and so is not nested. An order 'has a' customer.

I've setup my /customer/order/create controller to have

```
needs: "customer"
```

I want to access the customer in my /customer/order/create.hbs template like this:

```
<h3>New Order for {{controllers.customer.name}}</h3>
```

When I end up creating the order I will also want to set `newOrder.customer = customer`.

customer.hbs links like so

```
<div>
  {{#link-to 'customer.order.create' model}}Create Order{{/link-to}}
</div>
```

Currently `{{controllers.customer.name}}` renders nothing, what piece of the puzzle am I missing to get to the customer in my order/create route?

Or putting it more generally, what route/controller/etc code do I need when I have a parent object which belongs to my child object in a /parentObject/parent_id/childObject/create type scenario.

Comment: {{controllers.customer}} is Controller Object, {{controllers.customer.name}} it's name property. I think you want {{controllers.customer.model.name}}

Comment: "..newOrder.customer = customer.." => newOrder.set('customer', this.get('controllers.customer.model'))

Comment: "...more generally..." => it is dependancy injection concept http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.12.0/understanding-ember/dependency-injection-and-service-lookup/

Comment: Thank you for the  `controllers.customer.model.name` suggestion - this works great via the link-to in customer.hbs, but accessing the url directly renders the customer name blank, do I need to add one other thing somewhere?

Comment: To answer last comment, show your `customer.order.create` route model hook, please.

Comment: It's currently empty, so that will be the bit I am missing

Comment: I've post completed answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many points to fix:

1) `{{controllers.customer}}` is Controller Object, `{{controllers.customer.name}}` it's name property. I think you want `{{controllers.customer.model.name}}`.

2) "..newOrder.customer = customer.." should be

```
 newOrder.set('customer', this.get('controllers.customer.model'));
```

3) your `customer.order.create` route `model` hook shoudn't be empty, since you are using dynamic segment `customer_id`:

```
//route
model: function(params) {
  return this.find('customer', params.customer_id);
}
```

4) Your routes are not nested, so `{{controllers.customer.model.name}}` would be empty if your `customer` route is not activated. So you should use: `{{model.name}}` instead of `{{controllers.customer.model.name}}`

When you click link you passes model directly, and `model` hook is not fired, so all looks good. When you visit url directly, `model` hook is fired. If it is empty you will see nothing.

**General concept**: it is dependancy injection concept, you could read here: http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.12.0/understanding-ember/dependency-injection-and-service-lookup/

Comment: Still having trouble with the direct url, is {{controllers.customer.model.name}} correct given the route in 3)?

Comment: I add about why {{controllers.customer.model.name}} sometimes does not work.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get the customer from the store. Give the following code a try:

The route:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      customer: this.store.find('customer', params.customer_id)
    });
  }
});
```

The controller:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  customer: Ember.computed.alias('model.customer')
});
```

And it should be directly accessible as `customer` in your template, like so:

```
<h3>New order for {{customer.name}}</h3>
```

Comment: Thanks Jon, what is the syntax to then access customer in my template with this as my route?

Comment: `{{model.customer.name}}` works on the direct url, but not coming through the link-to.

Comment: @Knightsy Gave my answer an update with some feedback on that.

Answer (score 0):

I changed `needs: "customer"` to `needs: ["customer"]` and then used `{{model.name}}` in my template. Seems that needs requires an array of strings and not just a string, after I fixed that Ember took compare of the rest without the need to create a /customers/order/create.js route.

For a more complete answer see Artych's answer if you don't want everything taken care of.